# OneLogin Java-SAML SP fails to provide signed metadata to Shibboleth IdP

Tags: java, metadata, saml, shibboleth, onelogin

When the sample application of OneLogin Java-SAML toolkit is configured to provide signed SP metadata to Shibboleth IdP, the IdP rejects the metadata signature complaining about **invalid transform** used in the signing process. However, the validation of the signature by standard XML tools like oXygen editor and the like succeeds.

The java-saml-tookit-jspsample-2.2.0 application has been configured to provide signed metadata to IdP (`onelogin.saml2.security.sign_metadata = true`) and the IdP's metadata-providers.xml contains configuration block using file-backed HTTP requiring signature validation.

What is wrong on this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of googling I found a similar issue in other software. The Java-SAML toolkit by OneLogin uses a cannonicalization method to sign the metadata that is legal, but it is **NOT explicitly allowed** by the SAML standard. If you check the section 5.5.4 of SAML2 specification, it states explicitly:

> Signatures in SAML messages SHOULD NOT contain transforms other than
>   the enveloped signature transform (with the identifier
>   http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature) or the
>   exclusive canonicalization transforms (with the identifier
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n# or
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments). Verifiers of
>   signatures MAY reject signatures that contain other transform
>   algorithms as invalid.

The Java-SAML toolkit has a hard-wired setting for this using `http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments` instead that gets rejected by Shibboleth IdP. If you want to get things going, download the source of the Java-SAML toolkit from OneLogin, unpack it, and then change line 1056 of java-saml-2.2.0/core/src/main/java/com/onelogin/saml2/util/Util.java from

```
String c14nMethod = Constants.C14N_WC;
```

to

```
String c14nMethod = Constants.C14NEXC_WC;
```

Recompile using maven (mvn package) and re-deploy the application.